# Why this output [gh]{2}

Tags: java, regex

[gh]{2}
look for 2 instances of either g or h, that is how I read the above regex :

> Enter your regex: [gh]{2}
>   Enter input string to search: ghkkk
>   I found the text "gh" starting at index 0 and ending at index 2.

As per my understanding, how I read the above regex, the input string (ghkkk) should not have any match, as there are no two instances of either g or h. However it finds a match.

I used the [program given on oracle official website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html).

Can somebody please explain why I got the match?

Comment: just think of `{n}` as repeating the pattern before it, so your expression reads like `[gh][gh]`. To do what you want to do, you could use `(gg|hh)` or `(g{2}|h{2})`

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you very much for your answer, I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

`[gh]{2}` is shorthand for `[gh][gh]`. `ghkkk` matches `[gh][gh]` (`g` in the first group, `h` in the second) thus it matches its shorthand `[gh]{2}`.

To match just `gg` and `hh` use `gg|hh` (the shortest regexp for that).

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer, I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid your interpretation isn't quite right. The regex matches `gg`, `hh`, `gh` and `hg`.

To match just `gg` or `hh`, use `gg|hh`.

Comment: Yes you are right my interpretation was wrong, but now I got it from Mihai's answer. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

To match `gg` or `hh` use:

- `gg|hh`

[image]

*or*

- `g{2}|h{2}`
  [image]